# Object Visualforce Button Not Working in Salesforce Communities

Tags: visualforce, community, button

I have a Visualforce Button on one of my objects called `Configure`. It works fine in the Standard Salesforce view. I then created a Salesforce Community using the 'Visualforce+Tabs' template and when I click the button there, it throws the following error:

[image]

I am logged in using the System Administrator profile, but I am wondering if this is a permissions issue or some other configuration issue. Does the Community have a default profile that I am unaware of?

Comment: You did not include the url in your screenshot...seems like a useful data point.

Comment: My mistake. I have updated the screenshot with the URL.

Comment: What is the URL of the community? typically there is a path after the main URL right - not always but something to check? Also, what template are you using?

Comment: As I stated above, I am using the 'Visualforce+Tabs' template. I'm not sure about the community name, but the custom community URL is included in the screenshot. Here is another example URL from one of the pages that successfully loads: https://suryamanagedcommunity-developer-edition.na3.force.com/zqci09__quoteEnhancement?entityId=a005000000hDozgAAC&quoteType=Subscription&stepNumber=1  The custom domain name is included.